# The autocomplete drop-down menu does not show me the data

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm using an autocomplete. When I click on the input, a dropdown opens with all possible fields to select.

My problem is that the fields do not appear visible, I have already tested using z-index etc and so far nothing has worked.

How can I solve this?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aanvmj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Code**

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 10px;">
    <div class="ng-autocomplete auto">
        <ng-autocomplete [data]="countries" [searchKeyword]="keyword" 
         [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate" [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
        </ng-autocomplete>

        <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
            <a [innerHTML]="item.departamento"></a>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
            <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
        </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, the information is there, but it does not appear visible :(

Comment: _“As you can see in the image, the information is there”_ - how did you figure that? If I expect this in the browser dev tools, then all I see in those places are _empty_ link elements, `<a _ngcontent-aip-c0=""></a>` - so your data does _not_ appear to “be there” to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `#itemTemplate`, you need to bind `name` since it is the property in your json

Try like this:

```
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
    <a [innerHTML]="item.name"></a>
</ng-template>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcmr1v?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: It really worked, but in my case it still doesn't appear and I have everything pretty much right :( there must be some solution using css

Comment: You can check if you have imported the styles of the library